# Google Calendar v3 Error "The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past. [410]"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We are using the Google Calendar v3 API to return a list of events for a user that have been updated since a point in time.

In the v2 API there was no limitation on setting this date in the past.

If we set the UpdatedMin to a date too far back (like 2 months) then the error is thrown

"The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past. [410]"

If we set ShowDeleted to false then we do not get the error.

I cannot find any reference to a limitation here.  Does anybody know the details of this limit.  Unfortunately when synchronising calendars this is a show stopper when synchronisation has not run for a period of time for a calendar (other than running a full list which we would prefer to avoid)

```
EventsResource.ListRequest lr = new EventsResource.ListRequest(service, c.uc.calendar); 

lr.UpdatedMin = c.primaryModTime.ToLocalTime();
lr.ShowDeleted = true;
Events el = lr.Execute();
if (el.Items.Count > 0)
{
```

the following also discusses this issue but without any resoluton.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-calendar-api/_rk9o45sXT0/3APXqxi8jvkJ

Comment: Did you ever find out any more on this? I had the same issue and started trying different dates--on 3/12/17, it wouldn't let me go back to 2/10/17, but it let me do 2/15/17, so it seems the limit is less than 30 days but greater than or equal to 25 days.

Comment: Sorry no definitive answer - from memory it is volume related also...  We use calendar notifications now rather than checking for modified dates.  If we get the 410 message we pull a full load and work with that.

Answer (score 4):

There is some explanation at:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

It says that on 410 you should wipe your storage and perform a full sync instead.

Also consider switching to sync tokens as recommended in the last paragraph.

Comment: Thanks luc - I hadn't seen the synchronization functionality in the v3 docs.  We are using the legacy approach so I suppose they are not offering a hard 'limit' for when a '410' occurs but rather saying that under that scenario a Full Load is required.  Would be nice to know what criteria will result in a 410.

Comment: agree, I mean at some point in the api processing it must identify too far against the supplied date. Surely it could give a response of eg 'minUpdateAvailable:2020-10-01'. Can we query the API for this ?