# Google Calendar API "The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past." after just one day

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

My code fetches calendar events using `service.events().list()` with the following parameters:

```
timeMax: 2015-11-13T04:12:44.263000Z
timeMin: 2014-05-17T04:12:44.263000Z
updatedMin: 2014-11-12T14:56:20.395000Z # = yesterday
```

I know there's a limit on the `updatedMin` param that prevents it to be too far in the past, but lately I get the following error even when `updatedMin` is **yesterday**:

> The requested minimum modification time lies too far in the past.

[Everywhere](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-calendar-api/_rk9o45sXT0/3APXqxi8jvkJ) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750856/google-calendar-v3-error-the-requested-minimum-modification-time-lies-too-far-i) [error](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308122) is mentioned, they are talking about a limit that is approx. 20 days in the past, certainly not one day.

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Comment: Using updatedMin is discouraged, consider switching to syncTokens: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Comment: @Tzach, I've been receiving it as well lately. Only on some accounts, though.

Comment: I've looked deeper into this, and for some users, it allows only about 11 hours into the past,

Comment: What did you do to solve this? I am getting this error for a user with updatedMin beyond 8 days in the past.

Comment: @Varun for some reason I can't remember, this error stopped appearing if `updatedMin` was less than ~14 days ago. So if we need more than that, we just fetch everything without setting `updatedMin` (not optimal, but working for a year).

Answer (score -1):

@Tzach, I tried the above query in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) with the same values and it returned the results without any error unless its greater than 20days. As Luc said, better to switch to syncTokens which saves the bandwidth.