# Get the list of created Google Calendar events for a specific user

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I was trying to get the number of events that a specific user created in the past month using Google Calendar API.

The problem is that I got all the events where a user was invited. I don't see how to query only the events that user created.

calendarId: user's email adress
updatedMin : today - one month

I am using Google's api explorer to query Calendar API.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Include a query parameter in your request:</strike>

q: `organizer==user@domain.com`

This will filter to only events organized by user@domain.com.

Updated:
Unfortunately the query parameter does not accept key value pairs. This solution will not work.

Comment: This does not seem to work. In the response i have 
    "items": [ "organizer": { "email": "someone_else@domain.com" }, ... ] 
so the filter is not taken into account :(

Comment: It looks like you're right. The 'q' parameter supports values only - not key value pairs. It does not look like there's a way to achieve what you want via query. The Apps Script solution proposed by NaziA is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter them by `creator.email` or `organizer.email`

#### Code:

```
function getCreatedEvents() {
  var user = 'user@domain.com';
  var today = new Date();
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  
  var args = {
    timeMin: new Date(date.getTime()).toISOString(),
    timeMax: new Date(today.getTime()).toISOString()
  }
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(user, args).items;

  events.forEach(function (event){
    if(event.creator && event.creator.email == user){
      // do something to events
      Logger.log(event);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### References:

- [DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097699/google-apps-script-datetime-format)
- [UpdatedMin Error1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750856/google-calendar-v3-error-the-requested-minimum-modification-time-lies-too-far-i)
- [UpdatedMin Error2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904159/google-calendar-api-the-requested-minimum-modification-time-lies-too-far-in-the#comment42360809_26904159)
- [Calendar.Events.List](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: Hi, I am using a request tester directly from the https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3 I dont see where could I put and test the code

Comment: I am not sure as to how you add a filter in the tester. Query should be in the `q` text box, but I'm not sure what's the format. I have tried to make it work but I can't seem to query properly using conditionals. Although I prefer you use Apps Script as it is much better and more flexible.